# PHP fsockopen not work for localhost

Tags: php, fsockopen

use the php function of fsockopen() to Asynchronous request，
when the host is 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' or the domain name of this server.It does't work.
if the host is local area network ip（eg.192.168.3.11） address，It worked。

and the server can receive fsockopen request from other server on internet，also can send fsockopen request to other server on internet。

my code:

```
function async_post($host,$path,$data){

    $post = http_build_query($data);
    $len = strlen($post);
    $fp = fsockopen( $host , 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo "$errstr ($errno)\n";
    } else {

        $out = "POST $path HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: $host\r\n";
        $out .= "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n";
        $out .= "Content-Length: $len\r\n";
        $out .= "\r\n";
        $out .= $post."\r\n";
        fwrite($fp, $out);
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

Suppose the problem server' domain name is :www.problem.com
It's Internet ip is :8.8.8.8
It's local area network ip is：192.168.0.123
Suppose a third-party server' ip is :9.9.9.9

problem server send request:

async_post("127.0.0.1",'xxx.php',$data) **not work**

async_post("localhost",'xxx.php',$data) **not work**

async_post("www.problem.com",'xxx.php',$data) **not work**

async_post("9.9.9.9",'xxx.php',$data)  **work**

third-party server send request:

async_post("www.problem.com",'xxx.php',$data)   **work**

Comment: Do you have access to the server? It might be worth checking it is listening on all interfaces. Check with: `netstat -a | grep http`

Comment: I don't know the reason why SRE do that